# Wifi disconnection issues for rtw_8822ce

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04

So I've been facing the below issues since a few months. They were never that bothersome, as they occurred once a few weeks. A simple restart would work then. Now however, they occur every few minutes, which has made the wifi on my device absolutely unusable. I couldn't find a fix to this by myself. Hence, could somebody pls help me out here haha

Background:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64
Host: ASUS TUF Gaming A17 FA706IH_
Kernel: 5.15.0-60-lowlatency
```

Problem:

```
Sometimes wifi disconnects suddenly. It also fails to detect any networks when opened from settings.
At other times, it does detect networks, but fails to connect to them.
At times it remains connected to networks without actually having any internet access.
```

On running dmesg, here is what I get:

```
================================================================================
[ 27.787744] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /home/fenrir/rtw88/rtw8822c.c:4449:20
[ 27.787745] index 3 is out of range for type 'u8 [2][4]'
[ 27.787746] CPU: 6 PID: 276 Comm: kworker/u32:4 Tainted: P W OE 5.15.0-60-lowlatency #66-Ubuntu
[ 27.787747] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ASUS TUF Gaming A17 FA706IH_FA706IH/FA706IH, BIOS FA706IH.316 03/12/2021
[ 27.787748] Workqueue: phy0 rtw_watch_dog_work [rtw_core]
[ 27.787753] Call Trace:
[ 27.787754]
[ 27.787754] show_stack+0x52/0x5c
[ 27.787755] dump_stack_lvl+0x4a/0x63
[ 27.787757] dump_stack+0x10/0x16
[ 27.787759] ubsan_epilogue+0x9/0x49
[ 27.787761] __ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds.cold+0x44/0x49
[ 27.787763] ? rtw8822c_phy_cck_pd_set+0x40c/0x820 [rtw_8822c]
[ 27.787765] rtw8822c_phy_cck_pd_set+0x5c6/0x820 [rtw_8822c]
[ 27.787767] ? rtw_write32_mask+0x6c/0xa0 [rtw_8822c]
[ 27.787771] rtw_phy_dynamic_mechanism+0x347/0x720 [rtw_core]
[ 27.787777] rtw_watch_dog_work+0x1dd/0x270 [rtw_core]
[ 27.787782] process_one_work+0x222/0x400
[ 27.787784] worker_thread+0x50/0x3f0
[ 27.787785] ? process_one_work+0x400/0x400
[ 27.787786] kthread+0x13b/0x160
[ 27.787788] ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
[ 27.787790] ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
[ 27.787792]
[ 27.787793] ================================================================================
[ 27.790852] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 27.793920] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 27.797062] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 28.097975] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x000c address=0xaef140b0 flags=0x0000]
[ 29.828972] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 29.832059] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 29.835154] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 29.838290] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 31.812918] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 31.816009] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 31.819164] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 33.796964] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 33.800052] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 33.903942] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 33.907009] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 35.844931] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 35.848009] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 35.851084] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 35.854209] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 37.828947] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 37.832046] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 37.835174] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 39.813929] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 39.817015] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 39.820153] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 41.796942] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 41.800045] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 41.903932] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 43.844919] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 43.848000] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 43.851059] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 43.854180] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 45.828967] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 45.832056] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 45.835201] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 47.812945] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 47.816020] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[ 47.819153] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to send h2c command
```

In other times, I also get errors in the dmesg like:
mac power on failed or failed to poll offset something something.

I also get this many times:

````
[ 756.074974] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.074979] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.074998] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075006] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075009] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075017] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075023] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075032] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075040] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075048] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075056] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075064] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075073] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075085] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075091] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075096] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075103] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075112] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075121] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075129] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075138] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status
[ 756.075213] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: pci bus timeout, check dma status```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update of everything that happened since I made this post.

1. I talked to the maintainer of this wifi driver [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88/issues/116). They said that my output was not usual and was definitely spitting out errors. They tried talking to a contact that they had at Realtek. Meanwhile, just for the sake of it, I plugged my wifi card out, cleaned it and put it back in. The issue that I faced went away. After a week had passed, I informed them of the same and that is where our conversation ended.
2. After around a month however, the issue started to come back. It was clear then that this was more of a hardware issue than a software issue. After more digging for information about this specific card, I saw that there were quite a few people complaining about the bad quality of the card and how they had to replace it within a year or two. I can't provide a link for this as it was a while ago. I think this was on the ASUS TUF subreddit and probably Hubzilla too.
3. I tried my plug in plug out trick again, but looks like it had stopped working. Therefore, I had no other option than buying a new wifi card for this. I bought the cheapest branded wifi card that I could from Amazon. [Here it is](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B0721MLM8B/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). I installed it more than 6 months ago, and it has been working without any wifi issues. Unfortunately, this move also took out my bluetooth capabilities. I don't know if this is a hardware limitation or a software one. Whatever it is, I don't really care as I almost never even used bluetooth with my laptop. Plus, I didn't have money to buy wifi+bluetooth cards that were a lot more expensive for me than this one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Still needs more detail.

Comment: Please give more detailed answare. You're honestly crucial to solve this issue no one has solved before